# Can WSL inherit my windows AD permissions

Tags: networking, windows-10, authentication, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to use WSL sometimes because there's a bunch of tools I like which either run badly or not at all on Windows directly. Most of these tools involve connecting to MSSQL databases. Directly from windows this is easy, they'll just use windows auth and let me in - hurrah. From WSL that no longer works and I have to pass my credentials manually.

Is there a way to make programs running in WSL 'inherit' the authentication capabilities of my windows user?

Thanks
Dan